# Unique identifier using or condition in Python or SQL

Tags: python, sql, group-by

I have a table where I want to group observations based on two separate fields. I want to use an **OR** condition (as opposed to the conventional **AND** clause hidden within the groupby command).

For example, consider the following 3 rows:

**Name** - **Email**

Name1 - name1@email.com

Name2 - name1@email.com

Name2 - name2@email.com

I want to assign a unique identifier to this customer since they have an overlap in both name and email.

Is there any way to do this in Python or SQL?

Comment: I'm not sure what the full solution is, but I think it involves a self-join on t1.name = t2.name OR t1.email = t2.email.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1='condition1' OR col2='condition2';`

You can also still use a GROUPBY if you want:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1='condition1' OR col2='condition2' GROUPBY col1;`

Comment: I think he wants to find all the groups of rows that are similar in the two column, not specific rows.

Comment: He's looking for a `GROUP BY` condition, not `WHERE`.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as I'd like to repeat the query for many customers who fit the criteria of same name or email.

Comment: I think this query pushes the limits of what you're supposed to be doing in SQL, since this basically involves reading the entire `name` and `email` column on every `SELECT` (or `INSERT`).  Ideally you would have a `PRIMARY KEY` definition that would constrain a customer from using multiple names for the same email address or multiple email addresses for the same name.  Then it's just a simple join with another table to find out who the customer is.  Do you have full control over the database or are otherwise able to restructure the schema?